# angularJS one animation after another

Tags: angularjs, animation, callback

I'm using angularJS(no jQuery) to make pagination animation effect, that is when user asks records of the next page, the current table rows in a table slide out to the right, and the table rows that contains the asked records would slide in from the right.

```
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="userInfo in data.entries" class="row-animate">
        <th ng-bind="userInfo.email"></th>
        <th ng-bind="userInfo.role"></th>
        <th ng-bind="userInfo.createdAt"></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The animation effect is done with .row-animate, the css looks like so:

```
.row-animate.ng-enter {
    .animate(1s, fadeInRight);
}
.row-animate.ng-leave {
    .animate(1s, fadeOutRight);
}
```

Problem is that when user clicks next page, the sliding out animation of the old records and sliding in animation of the new records happen at the same time, which makes the view kinda messy... Is there a way to let the old records slide out first, after the old ones are completely gone, then the new ones slide in?

Comment: Are they overlapping during the animation, or is one below the other?

Comment: Using `position: absolute` in any way to make them overlap?

Comment: Well, overlap is not a problem for me, what I want is for the first animation to finish and then the second animation to start, this is easy in jquery but I don't know how I can achieve this using angularJS

Comment: I understand, but I'm trying to replicate your scenario so I can try the different solutions I have in mind. If you could replicate a scenario in Plunker it would be much easier to help :)

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't use position: absolute, just the bootstrap grid layout and default bootstrap table style.

Comment: Tried to replicate it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rA1eXBx14NafXWJYOJLm?p=preview But I guess this is not the problem you are getting then.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly the problem I'm facing, thanks dude! Sorry that I'm no good at plunker, will definitely try to learn how to use plunker. Anyhow, what I'm expecting is for the old table lines to fade out completely, and then the new table lines to slide in. Any ideas?